# Re-calculate fragment normals after modifying vertex position

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

the following pen is my original code

https://codepen.io/johnhckuo/pen/RxrXxX

I've changed the height of terrain using perlin noise, and now I want to put some directional light on the terrain.

However, the normals of terrain seem to be remain unchanged. 
So how can I re-calculate the normal of each fragment?

Here is my code of vertex shader:

```
  vNormal = normal;
  uVu = uv;
  modelPosition = position;
  vec2 st = uVu.xy * frequency;
  vec3 pos = vec3(st.x, st.y, 100.0);
  vec3 newPosition = position + normal * noise(pos) * depth;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                modelViewMatrix *
                vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
```

And this is my code of fragment shader:

```
  vec2 st = uVu * frequency;
  vec3 pos = vec3(st.x, st.y, 100.0);
  vec3 sunColor = vec3(0.298, 0.662, 0.450);
  vec3 color = = diffuseLight(vNormal, 5.0, sunColor);    
  gl_FragColor = vec4( color, 1.0);
```

Also, is it less efficient to generate perlin noise using CPU than using GPU?

Comment: Why not apply the outcome of the `noise` function not only on the vertex position but also its normal?

Comment: @Matso I've tried what you suggested, but the result seems the same. But I think this solution is viable! Wondering where have I done wrong @@

Comment: Actually, to get better effects and finer details in shading, You should fiddle with normals at the level of fragments. In Your case that would require implementing a per fragment version of `noise` function (or simply using it in a fragment shader).

Comment: @Rabbid76 hmm, I've tried what you said but it turns out that the whole terrain becomes black.